# google maps autocomplete, hook before the display results

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Is there any way to put an hook to the even before typed results are displayed ? I want to filter the ones which are not fitting to my need (ie not in the country that I implement).

Here is my current code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places&language=es&region=MX" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function hebe(){
        var defaultBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
          new google.maps.LatLng(18.2397859708389,-99.876708984375),
          new google.maps.LatLng(20.23127464130257,-97.899169921875)
        );

        var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');

        autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
        autocomplete.setBounds(defaultBounds)
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body onLoad="hebe();">
      <input id="searchTextField" type="text" size="50">
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly `componentRestrictions`?

> `componentRestrictions` can be used to restrict results to specific groups. Currently, you can use componentRestrictions to filter by country. The country must be passed as as a two character, ISO 3166-1 Alpha-2 compatible country code.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#adding_autocomplete